# Flutter call multiple http not working in release mode

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous

Hi iam trying to call 2 HTTP  in one flutter widget - in dubug mode its working fine but in release its not working
I grant the internet permission in the android manifest
this is my code

```
void online() async {
      category = await catg.getdeliverydone();
     pcategory = await catg.getpartialdeliverydone();
}
```

also I tried  `final results = await Future.wait([ponline1(), online()]);`

but also no luck
Again, when I run the app in debug mode everything works perfectly and it give me all the needed data
same code just build it as release

```
flutter build apk --release
```

when I install the release it does not work - no code has been changed the API is working and I see data coming from the API but flutter does not show it -even if it was 1 record in each call
can anyone give me a solution thanks

Comment: It probably works as if it works in debug it should work in release. Wait for all data to load first then after all data has been loaded, build the widgets.

Comment: no it isn't , in debug in 2 seconds it gets data but in release nothing at all

Comment: Just add a loader as long as data is not found. If url in release is same as debug, it should work. In release mode, data takes longer to arrive from experience. Widgets sometimes build way before data is fetched.

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony can you please send me example

Comment: If you post your codes, where you fetch the values and set the values to a widget. I probably can help you with it.

Comment: Run your code as release mode from build in Android Studio, you can see where the error occurs

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978223/flutter-http-get-request-doesnt-work-on-apk-release

Comment: Can you add the both main and debug Androidmanifest files